# How to remove Key pairs in a line and print only the values after : in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, concatenation

```
I am pretty new to python, The text i have is in text file like : 
{u'metro_name': u'Phoenix-Mesa-Glendale, AZ', u'ips': 38060}
{u'metro_name': u'Los Angeles-Long Beach-Glendale, CA  (MSAD)', u'ips': 31100}
```

How to print only the Values in Python and concat them with $ in a single line i.e the output :

```
'Phoenix-Mesa-Glendale, AZ$$38060','Los Angeles-Long Beach-Glendale, CA  (MSAD)$$31100'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that regex can't fully parse string literal syntax, so it's more work than it's worth here. Consider using `ast.literal_eval` to turn each line into a dictionary. Then you can do whatever string manipulation you like on their values.

```
import ast
from collections import OrderedDict
dicts = []
with open("data.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        d = ast.literal_eval(line)
        d = OrderedDict((k, d[k]) for k in ('metro_name', 'ips'))
        dicts.append(d)

output_lines = []
for dict in dicts:
    values = [str(value) for value in dict.values()]
    line = "$$".join(values)
    output_lines.append(repr(line))
print ",".join(output_lines)
```

Result:

```
'Phoenix-Mesa-Glendale, AZ$$38060','Los Angeles-Long Beach-Glendale, CA  (MSAD)$$31100'
```

Comment: `dict.values()` produces the values in an arbitrary order (only in cPython 3.6+ the order will be preserved, but that is an implementation detail and should not be relied on), so your example only works by accident. It could also produce `38060$$Phoenix-Mesa-Glendale, AZ` ...

Comment: Does it output to a file and a variable?

Comment: Ah, i Use python2.7

Comment: @mata, good observation. I've edited the code to use an OrderedDict.

Comment: @Viv, right now it outputs to stdout. Instead of doing `print ...` you could do `result = ...`, and then write `result` to a file in the usual way.